# ¿Cómo sumar los números de dos listas, posición por posición?

Tags: python, python-3.x

BN
Dada una lista, de dos valores, como seria posible ir sumando valores desde otra lista a esos valores y que se vayan almacenando?

```
list1=[0,1]

list2={1,3}

resultado esperado:
list1 =[1,4]
```

y asi en lo sucesivo

es un ejemplo sencillo porque hay otro mas complejo que no lo entiendo 
gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de forma sencilla con `Numpy` convirtiendo las listas a arrays.

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
array_2 = np.array([1,1,1,0,0])

In[1]: array_1 + array_2
Out[1]: array([2, 3, 4, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Gracias Alberto.

Comment: De nada @MaykelContrerasCamacho . Una forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow si crees que es la respuesta adecuada a la pregunta,  es marcando la respuesta como "respuesta correcta". Y porque no, dar un punto positivo a dicha respuesta/pregunta. Esto no solo me ayuda a mí, si no que hace que la pregunta tenga un mejor posicionamiento y puedas ayudar a otras personas que tenían la misma duda que tú a encontrarla :)

Answer (score 2):

otra forma:

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(list1,list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar la librería estándar.

La función **map()** : *Ejecuta una función sobre cada uno de los elementos de un iterador y devuelve un [iterador](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/11/iteradores-y-generadores.html)*.

Tenemos una `list`: `list1` y un `set`: `list2` como en tu ejemplo. Y le aplicamos `map` que recibe la función `sum` para los elementos generados en `[list1,list2]`, finalmente nos devolverá el iterador y para ver los datos lo convertimos en *lista*.

```
list(map(sum,[list1,list2]))
```

output:

```
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,1,1,0,0]
list3 = [x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
print(list3)  # [2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```